Error while installing CU for September 2024 (kb5002639) on SharePoint 2019 Front end server
We have a sharepoint Farm consists of 4 servers (2 front end servers and 2 backend servers). I successfully installed security patch for september 2024 (sts2019-kb5002639-fullfile-x64-glb) on 3 server. But installation failed on one of the front end server giving Error Failed to run the identification Don't understand what is the problem? What should I need to fix?

Here are a few steps you can try to resolve it:

Check Prerequisites: Ensure that all prerequisites for the update
are met. This includes having the latest .NET updates and any
previous required SharePoint updates installed.
Run as Administrator: Make sure you are running the update installer
with administrative privileges. Right-click the installer and select
“Run as administrator”.
Review Logs: Check the SharePoint ULS logs and the Windows Event
Viewer for more detailed error messages. Look for any specific
errors that might give more insight into why the identification
failed.
Configuration Wizard: After installing the update, run the
SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard. This can help resolve any
configuration issues that might be causing the error.


I did all the steps above but no success..!!
